# Not getting result with Eventful API[JSON]

Tags: java, json, request

I am trying to use Eventful API to get a list of events nearby but wasn't able to get any result with the request. 
Does anyone know what is the problem here?

This is my JSON request:  String url_request = "http://eventful.com/json/events?q=music&l=Singapore&api_key=" + API_KEY;

This is my current output :

{"sponsored_search_data":null,"location":{"geo_ip_fail":"0","location_type":null,"location_id":null,"geo_ip_guess":null,"meta_name":"Worldwide","pretty_name":"Worldwide"},"localized_base_url":"http://eventful.com","is_default_eventful_site":"1","facebook_app_namespace":"eventful","home_url":"/"}

```
package EventTest.EventTest;

import java.io.IOException;
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Request;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Response;


public class App 
   {
      private static final String API_KEY = "my_api_key";
      OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

      public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException 
   {
    App request = new App();

    String url_request = "http://eventful.com/json/events?q=music&l=Singapore&api_key=" + API_KEY;
        String response = request.run(url_request);

    System.out.println(response);

}

public String run(String url) throws IOException {
    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();

    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    return response.body().string();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Manage to obtain desired result by changing the JSON request :

String url_request =

"http://api.eventful.com/json/events/search?keywords=music&location=Singapore&app_key=my_app_key";